Cannot connect to WPA3 using Dell Windows10 22H2
I have a personal Dell Latitude 7400 with all the driver updated. And windows 10 22H2
When I tried connect to WPA3 network I can't.  To WPA2  I can connect successfully.
I do see the SSID but after I tried to connect using password to the network that not connect.
The WiFi card is AC9560.
I enter to Dell support site and update all the drivers that didn't help(even after reboot of course)
In device manager I see that the version of driver AC9560 is 22.250.0.4  by Intel.
Another devices can connect to that network.
How can I fix that?

It's possible for a card to only support WPA3 on Windows 11. The drive itself must support WPA3. If Intel has chosen to only support WPA3 on Windows 11 driver there is nothing that can be done. However, if you are running 22.100.x, it should work. Are you?

What message(s) do you get when you try connecting? Do you see the network and begin authenticating and then it fails, or do you not see it, or you can't auth? Please give us a step-by-step narrative of what happens leading up to this issue and it occurring. What driver version(s)?  Did you go to the Dell support site? Is this a business-owned computer, or a personal device? Please EDIT your post to add this and any other relevant and helpful information to help us better understand what is going on.

What build of Windows 10?

@music2myear - Intel has support WPA3 on Windows 10 since 19H2. However, the current driver 23.90.0, only supports 22H2.

Have you checked at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000054783/wireless.html to see if the WiFi card supports WPA3??

@DrMoishePippik - It does. Which is the reason I suspect the driver.  I don't have faith in the assumption that the author downloaded and installed the driver instead of allowing Windows Update to install it.

@music2myear Windows 10 22H2

@DrMoishePippik According to your link, I have AC9560 and that need to support WPA3

@Ramhound I allow to WIndows update to update all. And to Del also. In device manager I see that the driver of AC9560 is 22.250.0.4  by Intel

@dookilo12 Can any other device connect on WPA3? Could it be that the network is not set up to allow your laptop?

@AndrewMorton another device can connect to that network.

@dookilo12 Please answer all the questions in music2myear's first comment.

@AndrewMorton I answer the most points in the post , that personal laptop, and I do see the SSID and fail after I try to connect. I will attach the error withing few hours

@dookilo12 -  22.250.0.4 isn't the current driver (it's over a year old).  So that would be the reason WPA 3 does not function on Windows 10.

@Ramhound When I click on driver details and search for online update the windows does not found any update.so I guess there is no update for that driver that compatible for my Windows

Install the driver manually. The current driver is 23.90.0

@Ramhound yes! I did that and that fix the problem.  Please write that as answer and I accept that https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/99446/intel-wirelessac-9560/downloads.html
